# Do I need to cancel Stream<QuerySnapshot> (flutter)

Tags: flutter, memory, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I am listening to a collection of documents in firestore (as part of a chat app). I am doing this by using a service, which creates a `Stream<QuerySnapshot>` as follows:

```
_snapshots$ = Firestore.instance.collection('messages').orderBy('date',descending: false).snapshots()
```

I then create a StreamBuilder as follows:

```
return StreamBuilder<List<Message>>(
        stream: widget.chatService.messages$,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => (snapshot.hasData)
...
```

I am wondering if I need to detach this stream in the dispose method containing the `StreamBuilder` widget. I don't know much about Streams and StreamBuilders, so I'm not sure how to do this, but I really want to avoid any memory leaks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are right to worry about this, but `StreamBuilder` will do all the heavy lifting for you, including subscribing and unsubscribing, so you don't have to worry about it **if `StreamBuilder` is the only place where your `Stream` is being listened to.** But if you are listening to the `Stream` yourself, then you will have to `cancel` the subscription on a `StatefulWidget` `dispose` method.

Comment: For those wondering, it's like `final subscription = stream.listen(...);` and then `subscription.cancel();`. I use this approach in `Provider`s and pass a future to the widgets (instead of a stream). So the provider controls the rebuilds based on other conditions.

Answer (score 4):

Someone should correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that's the point of the `StreamBuilder` class:  [Looking at the source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart), it seems to unsubscribe on `dispose()` naturally.