# Is streamBuilder Widget needs to be disposed?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I already know  if I want to use `stream listen in method` to a snapshot so i need to use `StreamSubscription` then dispose it using `.cancel();`

but what if use `streamBuilder` under build method to get data from `fisrstore`, do i need to dispose it too if yes HOW ?.. or it will be disposed it self when I press back bottom ?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

          
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(widget.userId).snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot)  {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return circulearProgress();

              }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `StreamBuilder` automatically manages the lifecycle of the underlying stream you pass it. You don't need to do anything for that yourself here, it will auto-close the stream (and remove the listener from Firestore) when the widget disappears from the UI that your `build` method returns.

Also see:

- [Flutter: Streambuilder - Closing of streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662255/flutter-streambuilder-closing-of-streams)
- [Do I need to cancel Stream<QuerySnapshot> (flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087457/do-i-need-to-cancel-streamquerysnapshot-flutter)