# Flutter : Close streambuilder when navigating to next screen

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

Many SO questions explains that

> Streambuilder

manages its stream by itself and unsubscribe to the stream in its onDispose method.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/async.dart#L131

[Is streamBuilder Widget needs to be disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70206253/is-streambuilder-widget-needs-to-be-disposed)

Other Flutter Github questions explains that

> dispose or  deactivate

methods are not called when navigating to the next screen.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/50147#issuecomment-1033773923

So How to make Streambuilder from 1st screen unsubscribe when navigating to a 2nd screen?

With :

1. a 1st screen with streambuilder using a stream from a function calling Firestore snapshots
2. a 2nd screen having also a streambuilder using a stream from same function (calling Firestore snaphots but with different parameters)

When calling the Firestore stream on 2nd screen, i have noticed that the stream results get duplicated due to the streambuilder of 1st screen still listening to stream.